# From a given nested dictionary, find all the nested keys sequences

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

I have a nested dictionary which looks like this:

```
dct = {"A": {"AA": "aa", "BB": {"BBB": "bbb", "CCC": "ccc"}}}
```

I want to extract all the key sequences in the list format till I reach the deepest key:value pair.

The expected output is something like this:

```
["A->AA", "A->BB->BBB", "A->BB->CCC"]
```

The solution I tried is:

```
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            # traverse nested dict
            for x in find_keys(v):
                yield "{}_{}".format(k, x)
                print("{}_{}".format(k, x))
        else:
            yield k
            print(k)
```

but it doesnot seem to work as expected.

Comment: Works for me (if I add obvious missing lines). What is your full code? [ask] [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are almost there (or omitted some parts by mistake):

```py
def find_keys(dct):
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from (f"{k}->{x}" for x in find_keys(v))
        else:
            yield k

dct = {"A": {"AA": "aa", "BB": {"BBB": "bbb", "CCC": "ccc"}}}
print(*find_keys(dct)) # A->AA A->BB->BBB A->BB->CCC
```

If you want to use `return` instead, then:

```py
def find_keys(dct):
    result = []
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result += [f"{k}->{x}" for x in find_keys(v)]
        else:
            result.append(k)
    return result
```

Comment: Is there any way to return a list from the function. I searched online, and found that *yield* is similar to *return*, but thats not serving the purpose. It
I am expecting the output in the form of a list, e.g. ["A->AA", "A->BB->BBB", "A->BB->CCC"], so that I can use it for creating a column in the table.

Comment: @ChandraShakerBalure You can do `list(find_keys(dct))` to convert the output to a list. If you do want to use `return`, then see the updated part of the answer.